# Gremlin Python: Returning vertex IDs and edge properties in a list

Tags: python, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm having a hard time returning the exact information I'm looking for. Essentially, I want to return all edges (in either direction) of a certain type. I'd like to get the vertex IDs and the edge parameters in a list. Ideally, my output format looks like this:

```
{
    "from": "vertex_id_1",
    "to": "vertex_id_2",
    "similarity": 0.45
}
```

I've been using `g.both().vertexMap().toList()` to get the similarities, but I'm not able to get the vertex IDs this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the toy graph as an example, you can best do this with `project()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().bothE('knows').
......1>   project('from','to','weight').
......2>     by(outV().id()).
......3>     by(inV().id()).
......4>     by('weight')
==>[from:1,to:2,weight:0.5]
==>[from:1,to:4,weight:1.0]
==>[from:1,to:2,weight:0.5]
==>[from:1,to:4,weight:1.0]
```